# log4j PatternLayout Regex for throwables

Tags: logging, log4j, throwable, pattern-layout

I noticed from "https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout" that throwables (like exceptions) can be formatted (using '%throwable' : '%throwable{100}/'%throwable{short}' etc...).

Suppose I have the following in Java :
**logger.error("Exception in getUser :", ex);**

I have also the following Pattern Regex in the log4j xml settings file:
**"[%d] %logger{36} [%l] %-5level %m %n"**

I noticed that the exceptions logged at THE END of the log line even if the '%throwable' does not appear in the Pattern.

My question is : what is the default '%throwable' regex format ? where it is configured ?
Is it suppose to be like that ? logged at the end of the error log line ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see for `"@m @n"` if you don't specify what to do with `@throwble`, it will inject default `@throwable` at the end of message (so exception message + stack trace).

You can customize that just by adding `"@m @throwable{X} @n"`, where **X** is something you can choose from [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout) under the section **ex|exception|throwable**. For example `"@m @throwable{none} @n"` will suppress error message.